# My beer is not carbonating in bottles

Tags: beer

I followed the instruction, but did one week more on secondary fermentation than it is supposed to be. After I bottled it, one week passed i didn't see any bubbles in the bottle. Did the yeast run out and no more further carbonation?

Comment: Have you cracked open a bottle to see if it's carbonated?  You won't necessarily see bubbles in the bottle for conditioning.  Assuming you have cracked a bottle, and it is in fact no carbonated, we're going to need a lot more information from you.  What was your original gravity before fermentation?  What was your final gravity the day that it went into bottles.  What yeast did you use?  How old do you believe the kit was (fresh off the shelves, years old)?  What was the recipe?  Even step-by-step playback of the brew day would help.  How long did you ferment for?

Comment: Did you add sugar to the bottles, and if so how much?

Comment: I bought the beer kit, everything I did is from the instruction.I haven't opened one yet. I will wait one more week and see if they are ok. Thanks to all.

Comment: I'll put it this way, if you see any signs of active fermentation by visually inspecting the bottle, you probably put a dangerous amount of sugar in the bottles, and I would get rid of them yesterday (bottle bombs kill), or vent them frequently by popping the caps and applying new ones.  Since you followed the instructions and used the sugar in the kit, it of course is portioned correctly for the levels of carbonation for the beer, and you are perfectly fine.  No visible fermentation or bubbles in bottles is a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

When you bottle condition, two things must happen:

1. You add a small amount of sugar (usually dextrose) before bottling, which ferments and produces CO2.  If you add too much, bottles explode.  Too little, and the beer will be less fizzy.  Typically 1/2 to 2/3 of a cup for 22L of beer.  Since this is fermenting, the temperature will have some impact on how long this takes.
2. Once the CO2 is produced, it needs to be absorbed into the beer.  This takes time.  If you open a bottle and it hisses but the beer is flat, the CO2 did not absorb into the beer yet.  It is easier for CO2 to absorb if the temperature is lower.

It can often take 2 weeks for this process to complete, and at 4 weeks the beer's taste will improve.

You're probably being impatient - or you forgot step 1.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe i am too impatient, I will wait one more week.

Comment: Sometimes it takes one week, sometimes it takes 3 weeks.  The  beer makes its own schedule.

Comment: Totally agree @DennyConn - I always regret drinking a beer when the last few bottles I consume are peak quality while the first were less so.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect to see bubbles in the bottle. Without opening a glass bottle, I don't think you can tell if it is carbonated or not. The exception to this is if it explodes, of course. Then you know it's carbonated (far too much).

When the bottle is under pressure, most of the produced CO2 remains dissolved into the liquid as it is produced, so you won't see bubbles rising to the surface.